# Why are the *IT.java integration tests not found by maven-failsafe-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have created some integration tests in a java project and I would like to run them with maven-failsafe-plugin but when I try to do so by running `mvn clean install`, the tests are not executed.
Here is my setup:

I have a multimodule maven project. I use junit5 for testing and my unit tests are executed correctly with maven-surefire-plugin. I can see that the integration tests are compiled as well and I can find them in `target/test-classes.`

Here are distilled contents of my project files:

```
// /pom.xml

<dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
     <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
       ...
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>${maven-failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
       <executions>
         <execution>
           <id>integration-test</id>
           <goals>
             <goal>integration-test</goal>
             <goal>verify</goal>
           </goals>
         </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
```

In module pom:

```
// /submodule1/pom.xml
     <build>
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

My test files have following path `/submodule1/src/test/java/com/example/integrations/*IT.java`
Here is an example test file:

```
public class ClientIT {
  @Test
  public void callRemoteServerTest() {
    ...
  }
```

When I run `mvn clean install` I can see the integration tests are not executed:

```
--- failsafe:3.2.5:integration-test (integration-test) @ submodule1 ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- failsafe:3.2.5:verify (integration-test) @ submodule1 ---
[INFO]
```

I thought that the files with **/*IT.java path should be executed by default. Why are they not?

Comment: Move the execution block out of the pluginManagement into the block you have mentioned with sub module 1 ...Also add the junit-jupiter-engine in stead of junit-jupiter...

Comment: Also more details https://github.com/khmarbaise/youtube-videos/tree/main/episode-2

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions but it didn't solve the problem. I changed the dependency and moved the execution block, but the integration-test phase still contains 0 tests run. Also why should the execution be outside the pluginManagement?  I copied that from the maven docs: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html#usage-in-multi-module-projects

Comment: I found what was wrong. I had mixed up junit-jupiter and junit4 dependencies and the integration tests were importing the junit4 annotations, but I did not setup the junit-vintage-engine. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: @RKCZ I am also similar problem. Could you please clarify what changes did you make? If possible include updated POM too.

Comment: @TechSawy I had both junit4 and junit-jupiter dependencies in my POM and I used the junit4 annotations in my test classes. When I removed the junit4 dependencies and updated the import statements, it solved the problem.